# Retrieving Sub Value Where Key Has a Slash

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am able to get the start and end times of the data below using the following map:

```
var id = data.map(function(par){
    return  "id :" +par.start+" key is: "+ par.end +"<br>";
})
document.write(id)
```

This returns an iteration of the start/end times from the entries. This is my data:

```
var data = [
  {
    "start": "2021-04-24T00:00:00.000Z",
    "end": "2021-04-25T00:00:00.000Z",
    "segments": [
      {
        "performanceCounters/processCpuPercentage": {
          "avg": 9.01
        },
        "customDimensions/Role": "CD"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "start": "2021-04-25T00:00:00.000Z",
    "end": "2021-04-26T00:00:00.000Z",
    "segments": [
      {
        "performanceCounters/processCpuPercentage": {
          "avg": 8.2
        },
        "customDimensions/Role": "CD"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "start": "2021-04-26T00:00:00.000Z",
    "end": "2021-04-27T00:00:00.000Z",
    "segments": [
      {
        "performanceCounters/processCpuPercentage": {
          "avg": 16.38
        },
        "customDimensions/Role": "CD"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "start": "2021-04-27T00:00:00.000Z",
    "end": "2021-04-28T00:00:00.000Z",
    "segments": [
      {
        "performanceCounters/processCpuPercentage": {
          "avg": 9.89
        },
        "customDimensions/Role": "CD"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "start": "2021-04-28T00:00:00.000Z",
    "end": "2021-04-29T00:00:00.000Z",
    "segments": [
      {
        "performanceCounters/processCpuPercentage": {
          "avg": 10
        },
        "customDimensions/Role": "CD"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "start": "2021-04-29T00:00:00.000Z",
    "end": "2021-04-30T00:00:00.000Z",
    "segments": [
      {
        "performanceCounters/processCpuPercentage": {
          "avg": 9.07
        },
        "customDimensions/Role": "CD"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "start": "2021-04-30T00:00:00.000Z",
    "end": "2021-04-30T21:25:37.936Z",
    "segments": [
      {
        "performanceCounters/processCpuPercentage": {
          "avg": 8.66
        },
        "customDimensions/Role": "CD"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The problem I am running into is that I need to get the "avg" value. This is nested under the performanceCounters/processCpuPercentage key but if I try the following, it fails as undefined because the / appears to be causing issues. Is there a way to properly escape this? Here is the call when I try to the avg value that is failing:

```
var id = data.map(function(par){
    return  "id :" +par.start+" key is: "+ par.segments.performanceCounters/processCpuPercentage.avg +"<br>";
})
document.write(id)
```

Comment: Try ``par.segments[0]['performanceCounters/processCpuPercentage'].avg``

Comment: Thanks, since I want to get each one, would it be par.segments['performanceCounters/processCpuPercentage'].avg

Comment: you mean if there are many segments? what do u want to do with the averages in the end result?

Comment: Nevermind, I only need the first entry as its only one entry for average within the performanceCounters/processCPUPercentage. Can you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the `segment` item at `index=0` for example and use the bracket notation to get its `performanceCounters/processCpuPercentage`:

```js
const data = [ { "start": "2021-04-24T00:00:00.000Z", "end": "2021-04-25T00:00:00.000Z", "segments": [ { "performanceCounters/processCpuPercentage": { "avg": 9.01 }, "customDimensions/Role": "CD" } ] }, { "start": "2021-04-25T00:00:00.000Z", "end": "2021-04-26T00:00:00.000Z", "segments": [ { "performanceCounters/processCpuPercentage": { "avg": 8.2 }, "customDimensions/Role": "CD" } ] }, { "start": "2021-04-26T00:00:00.000Z", "end": "2021-04-27T00:00:00.000Z", "segments": [ { "performanceCounters/processCpuPercentage": { "avg": 16.38 }, "customDimensions/Role": "CD" } ] }, { "start": "2021-04-27T00:00:00.000Z", "end": "2021-04-28T00:00:00.000Z", "segments": [ { "performanceCounters/processCpuPercentage": { "avg": 9.89 }, "customDimensions/Role": "CD" } ] }, { "start": "2021-04-28T00:00:00.000Z", "end": "2021-04-29T00:00:00.000Z", "segments": [ { "performanceCounters/processCpuPercentage": { "avg": 10 }, "customDimensions/Role": "CD" } ] }, { "start": "2021-04-29T00:00:00.000Z", "end": "2021-04-30T00:00:00.000Z", "segments": [ { "performanceCounters/processCpuPercentage": { "avg": 9.07 }, "customDimensions/Role": "CD" } ] }, { "start": "2021-04-30T00:00:00.000Z", "end": "2021-04-30T21:25:37.936Z", "segments": [ { "performanceCounters/processCpuPercentage": { "avg": 8.66 }, "customDimensions/Role": "CD" } ] } ];

const id = data.map(par =>
  `id : ${par.start} key is: ${par.segments[0]['performanceCounters/processCpuPercentage'].avg} <br>`
);

document.write(id);
```